# Sorting dates including undefined and null

Tags: javascript

Im trying to sort data in order of ending soonest. this is my code and you can see the console results below. The sort is working somewhat but not completely. Can anyone help?

I see its to do with the invalid date but I can't work out how to get around this. The Invalid date field is blank in the JSON data that's pulled in. Null/undefined I would like to be last.

```
if (this.sortBy === "ending") {
        filteredResults.sort((a, b) => {
          var aDate = new Date(a.metaData.t);
          var bDate = new Date(b.metaData.t);           
          console.log(b.metaData.t);         
          if (!aDate) {
            aDate = 99999999;          }
          console.log("adate" + aDate);
          if (!bDate) {
            bDate = 99999999;
          }
          console.log("bdate" + bDate);
          
          if (aDate > bDate) {
            return 1;
          }
          if (aDate < bDate) {
            return -1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
      }

      return filteredResults;
    },
```

Console.log data results

```
adateWed Nov 30 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
bdateTue Dec 13 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
adateWed Nov 30 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
bdateFri Sep 09 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
adateWed Nov 30 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
bdateWed Nov 30 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
adateWed Nov 30 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
bdateThu Dec 08 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
adateWed Nov 30 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
bdateMon Dec 05 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
adateInvalid Date
bdateTue Dec 13 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
adateInvalid Date
bdateFri Mar 31 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
adateInvalid Date
bdateSun Aug 20 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
adateInvalid Date
bdateTue Jan 01 2030 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
adateInvalid Date
bdateTue Dec 13 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
Invalid Date
```

Filtered results - the JSON is not exact here as its too big to add to this question. The format of the data is correct locally
(1 example I have XX most of the data for privacy reasons)

```
filteredResults {
 
K:"XX"
D:"XX"
N:"XX"
y:"XX"
t:"3 August 2022"
u:"XX"
X:"XX"
R:"XX"
T:"XX"
E:"XX"
}
```

.....
80 more rows like this but with various dates

Comment: What do you want to do with the invalid dates? Like, if date A is valid and B is null, how should they be sorted? Do you expect invalid dates not to appear, or to appear first or last?

Comment: Please add some sample values for `filteredResults` array with `metaData.t` property.

Comment: The output has little sense, you're loging during the sorting, not the result after

Comment: Null/undefined I would like to be last. Apologies I should have said this.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the value in advance and move unknown dates to the end of the array.

```
// assuming iso 8601 dates (same time zone or zulu), null or undefined
data.sort((a, b) =>
    !a.date - !b.date ||
    a.date.localeCompare(b.date)
);
```